# Creating a complicated nested loop

Tags: c++, loops, nested-loops

This was on my midterm. Talked to everyone, no one got it. Teacher doesn't give out answers and we never did anything like this in class. I'm at a loss. Please save me internet. This is programming 101 to give some context.

Here goes:

Create a **nested** loop with five different lines of numbers. On the first line print 0-9, the second 10-12, the third 5-7, the fourth 3-7, the fifth 13-17.

Comment: Is this a single nested loop? `for(...){ for(...){ } }`? Or multiple nested loops in breadth and/or depth?

Comment: That information wasn't given. If it prints out what she wants and a nested loop is involved, she doesn't care I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You can nest loops, and perform actions before and after each nested loop.

For example, the following complete program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "OuterBefore";
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            std::cout << "Inner";
        std::cout << "OuterAfter";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Will print `OuterBeforeInnerInnerOuterAfterOuterBeforeInnerInnerOuterAfter`.

This is the technique, you will need to modify it to solve your class problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response Steve, but yes, I already I understand that. If it was something that simply I wouldn't have a problem. I understand nested loops for the most part. It's the 'modify it to solve your class problem' I can't seem to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

We are given the following requirements for the problem:

> On the first line print 0-9, the second 10-12, the third 5-7, the fourth 3-7, the fifth 13-17.

and

> If it prints out what she wants and a nested loop is involved, she doesn't care

Using this limited information, we can do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    const auto starts = std::array<unsigned, 5>{ 0, 10, 5, 3, 13 };
    const auto ends = std::array<unsigned, 5>{ 9, 12, 7, 7, 17 };

    for(auto i = 0u; i < 5u; ++i)
    {
        for(auto j = starts[i]; j <= ends[i]; ++j)
        {
            std::cout << j << " ";
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The simplest answer is usually the best, right?